# Mobile App and Web App Api Hitting

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I made an API in Asp.net. The API can be hit from mobile application and from web application. I want to detect the source from where my API call has been made. i.e. mobile application or web application.

Can you guyz please help me regarding identification.

Comment: Pass a querystring parameter indicating the source `?source=web` vs `?source=mobile`.

Comment: @mjwills instead of query string I would prefer to send the value in the header

Comment: That would also work @IpsitGaur. But proxy servers and the like are more likely to fiddle with headers rather than querystrings (in my experience). So a querystring is _slightly_ more reliable.

Answer (score 1):

use the [user-agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) header

```
var useragent=Request.Headers.UserAgent.ToString();
```

Browser will automatically send it with all requests (including AJAX), no-browser clients generally will not include such header and you need to add your custom value to header

```
HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "C# App");
```